# passing associative array via URL using http_build_query()

Tags: php, arrays

I have two pages:`page1.php` which consists of an associative array containing potential error messages from a form.

```
$errors array:

Array ( [password] => password is required. [email] => email is required. )
```

This array could  contain more errors or it could contain less.

---

Im trying to pass it via url to another page to be displayed next to the corrosponding form fields.

```
page1.php:

$a = http_build_query($errors);
header("Location: /test/page2.php?errors=".$a); 
exit();
```

URL:

```
http://localhost/test/page2.php?errors=password=password+is+required.&email=email+is+required.
```

However the url doesnt seem to be displaying correctly and when I get redirected to `page2.php` when I retrieve the $errors array, its no longer an array.

---

```
page2.php:

if(isset($_GET['errors'])){
$errors = $_GET['errors'];
print_r($errors);
```

---

```
$errors:
password=password is required.
```

Im trying to get the `$errors array` to display exactly like it does on `page1.php` before it is sent via url.

EDIT: NEW URL:

```
http://localhost/test/page2.php?a=errors%5Bpassword%5D=password+is+required.&errors%5Bemail%5D=email+is+required.
```

Comment: `http_build_query` uses the array keys as GET parameters to the url, no need to prepend `errors=`. You could use something like `$params = array("errors" => $errors); $a = http_build_query($params);` if you need them to be named correctly. This would resullt in `?errors[email]=...` etc. GET parameters.

Comment: Use session? Serialize and base64 encode the message?

Comment: @ccKep I tried using your method and I got errors[password]=password is required however the errors[email] is missing, any ideas why?

Comment: Are you certain it's in the `$errors` array in the first place? Can you add the new code to your question (with the generated URL)?

Comment: @ccKep yeah just added the new URL

Comment: You're still prepending something. `http_build_query` generates a string with `key=value` entries concatenated using `&`. Just use `header("Location: /test/page2.php?".$a);` to add those to your URL.

Comment: @ccKep thank you for helping, I got it working now and understand better how http_build_query works now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're building your URL wrong, here's an example that should get you going:

```
// Just as an example:
$errors = array(
    "password" => "password is required",
    "email" => "email is required"
);

$queries = array(
    "errors" => $errors
);

$queryString = http_build_query($queries);

// This results in the string
// "errors%5Bpassword%5D=password+is+required&errors%5Bemail%5D=email+is+required"
// We simply append this to our header for the full redirect URL:

header("Location: /test/page2.php?".$queryString);

// The full url is then (for example):
// http://localhost/test/page2.php?errors%5Bpassword%5D=password+is+required&errors%5Bemail%5D=email+is+required
```

You can get those vars in page2.php like usual GET parameters:

```
$errors = $_GET["errors"];
```